# Clicking an image to change the url of a button

Tags: javascript, image, button, onclick

How could I make it that if *someone* clicks the image of the selected product to change the url of the button under the images

```
<div id="product">
  <img value="1" src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=Mary+Jane" alt="" />
  <img value="2" src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=LSD" alt="" />
  <img value="3" src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=Crack" alt="" />
</div>

<br>

<a id="buy" href="#"><button>Go to the the specific link</button></a>
```

*text/image for amusement only, they are not really the products*

What I have tried

```
window.onload = function() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('product');
    sel.onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("buy").href = "https://amazon.com/" + this.value;
    }
}
```

Here's a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdyWGa

Comment: what do you want the url of the button to change to?

Comment: Where's the element with the ID of product, and if you're using jQuery, why isn't there any in your example?

Comment: Sorry I see i forgot to put the ID's in the img's

The IMG's have an ID, when the image is clicked the URL should have the ID at the end

Comment: @j08691 I'm not using any jquery, I missclicked it sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery solution:

```
$(function(){
 $("img").click(function(){
    $("#buy").attr("href","https://amazon.com/"+$(this).attr("value"));
 });  
});
```

Javascript Version:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i=0, len=images.length, img; i<len; i++) {
   img = images[i];
   img.addEventListener("click", function() {  
      document.getElementById("buy").setAttribute("href", "https://amazon.com/"+ this.getAttribute("value"));
      alert("New href value: " + "https://amazon.com/"+ this.getAttribute("value"));
   });
}
```

#### Working fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqVjGY

Comment: The OP isn't using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a lot! its working but I don't want to use jquery, only vanilla js

Comment: I'm gonna post a plain javascript version soon...5 more minutes :)

Comment: @Eli, Javascript version added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="img1" src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=Mary+Jane" alt="" />
<img id="img2" src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=LSD" alt="" />
<img id="img3" src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=Crack" alt="" />

<br>

<a id="buy" href="#"><button>Go to the the specific link</button></a>
```

and:

```
$("#img1").on("click", function(){
$("#buy").attr("href","https://mynewurl.net");
});
```

here you describe clicking on which img will change url to what

Comment: The OP isn't using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript. Use `e.target` for take the current click element and get the value using attrubutes and apply to the href attribute.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('product');
    sel.onclick = function(e) {
      console.log( e.target.attributes[0].value)
     document.getElementById("buy").setAttribute('href', "https://amazon.com/" + e.target.attributes[0].value) ;
    }
}
```

[**CodeOpen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVgmxg)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to add a click event to all images to fetch the property value and add as an addition to href property of the intended element

```js
$(function(){
 $('img').on('click', function(){
   $('#buy').attr('href',"https://amazon.com/" + $(this).attr('value'));
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
  <img value="1" src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=Mary+Jane" alt="" />
  <img value="2" src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=LSD" alt="" />
  <img value="3" src="http://placehold.it/300x100?text=Crack" alt="" />
</div>
<a id="buy" href="#"><button>Go to the the specific link</button></a>
```